# couchdb-python change notifications

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I'm trying to use couchdb.py to create and update databases.  I'd like to implement notification changes, preferably in continuous mode.  Running the test code posted below, I don't see how the changes scheme works within python.

```
class SomeDocument(Document):

#############################################################################

#    def __init__ (self):

    intField  = IntegerField()#for now - this should to be an integer
    textField = TextField()

couch = couchdb.Server('http://127.0.0.1:5984')
databasename = 'testnotifications'

if databasename in couch:
    print 'Deleting then creating database ' + databasename + ' from server'
    del couch[databasename]
    db = couch.create(databasename)
else:
    print 'Creating database ' + databasename + ' on server'
    db = couch.create(databasename)

for iii in range(5):

    doc = SomeDocument(intField=iii,textField='somestring'+str(iii))
    doc.store(db)
    print doc.id + '\t' + doc.rev

something = db.changes(feed='continuous',since=4,heartbeat=1000)

for iii in range(5,10):

    doc = SomeDocument(intField=iii,textField='somestring'+str(iii))
    doc.store(db)
    time.sleep(1)
    print something
    print db.changes(since=iii-1)
```

The value

```
db.changes(since=iii-1)
```

returns information that is of interest, but in a format from which I haven't worked out how to extract the sequence or revision numbers, or the document information:

```
{u'last_seq': 6, u'results': [{u'changes': [{u'rev': u'1-9c1e4df5ceacada059512a8180ead70e'}], u'id': u'7d0cb1ccbfd9675b4b6c1076f40049a8', u'seq': 5}, {u'changes': [{u'rev': u'1-bbe2953a5ef9835a0f8d548fa4c33b42'}], u'id': u'7d0cb1ccbfd9675b4b6c1076f400560d', u'seq': 6}]}
```

Meanwhile, the code I'm really interested in using:

```
db.changes(feed='continuous',since=4,heartbeat=1000)
```

Returns a generator object and doesn't appear to provide notifications as they come in, as the CouchDB [guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/notifications.html) suggests ....

Has anyone used changes in couchdb-python successfully?

Comment: Further to these issues, when using with a remote server (e.g. Cloudant) errors are thrown for the 'since' oparg .... edit - this appears to be because cloudant does not store revisions as integers, rather as strings, which makes the since argument even more confusing!

Answer (score 7):

I use long polling rather than continous, and that works ok for me. In long polling mode `db.changes` blocks until at least one change has happened, and then returns all the changes in a generator object.

Here is the code I use to handle changes. `settings.db` is my CouchDB Database object.

```
since = 1
while True:
    changes = settings.db.changes(since=since)
    since = changes["last_seq"]
    for changeset in changes["results"]:
        try:
           doc = settings.db[changeset["id"]]
        except couchdb.http.ResourceNotFound:
           continue
        else:
           // process doc
```

As you can see it's an infinite loop where we call `changes` on each iteration. The call to `changes` returns a dictionary with two elements, the sequence number of the most recent update and the objects that were modified. I then loop through each result loading the appropriate object and processing it.

For a continuous feed, instead of the `while True:` line use `for changes in settings.db.changes(feed="continuous", since=since)`.

Answer (score 4):

I setup a mailspooler using something similar to this. You'll need to also load couchdb.Session() I also use a filter for only receiving unsent emails to the spooler  changes feed.

```
from couchdb import Server

    s = Server('http://localhost:5984/')
    db = s['testnotifications']
    # the since parameter defaults to 'last_seq' when using continuous feed
    ch = db.changes(feed='continuous',heartbeat='1000',include_docs=True)

    for line in ch:
        doc = line['doc']
        // process doc here
        doc['priority'] = 'high'
        doc['recipient'] = 'Joe User'
        # doc['state'] + 'sent'
        db.save(doc)
```

This will allow you access your doc directly from the changes feed, manipulate your data as you see fit, and finally update you document. I use a try/except block on the actual 'db.save(doc)' so I can catch when a document has been updated while I was editing and reload the doc before saving.