# Error: not found - missing when clicking on DB (Couchdb)

Tags: python, database, couchdb, couchdb-python

I am trying to view a Couchdb database in the browser named `event_db`. However, when I navigate to the following url: `http://localhost:5984/_utils/database.html?event_db` I get the an `Error: not found missing` and my url automatically redirects to `http://localhost:5984/_utils/database.html?event_db/_changes`.

This problem seemed to occur after I added `_changes` to the url and created a script checking the database for change here: [couchdb-python change notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840383/couchdb-python-change-notifications)

Has anyone ever experienced this problem? If so, how would I fix it?

My apologies I am new to Couchdb.

Thank you for your help,

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to clear my cache in my browser. After I did this, I was able to successfully navigate to the `event_db`.